# Meteor animation for added items

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, meteor

What's the best way of handling animations/transitions in Meteor, e.g having a fadeIn when a new item appears rather than it just appearing

Comment: A preliminary version of this is coming in meteor 0.8.2. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/1kUoG2mcaRw) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Weldon mentioned, Meteor is going to be adding some support for UI hooks in 0.8.2 and they will probably make it out into supported APIs by 1.0.

The original thread is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/1kUoG2mcaRw

Here are a few examples, including one I'm particularly happy with:

- https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-animated-each, demo at http://animated-each.meteor.com/
- https://github.com/percolatestudio/transition-helper

The first example causes items in a long scrollable container to fade in/out when added/deleted, and adjusts the scroll position so that other people who are scrolled to a different position in the container don't see a jump in their view.